# While using Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE parent version, SpringBootApplication class is not compiling

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to develop simple CRUD app using **Spring Boot Parent 2.3.0** and Postgresql.

Getting below errors in SpringBootApplication class and could not able to compile or run the project.

`- The type org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryLookupStrategy$Key cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

`- The type org.springframework.data.repository.config.BootstrapMode cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

[image]

[image]

[image]

On previous version of spring parent everything working fine. This issue is with 2.3.0.

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Whats the dependencies you are using from spring?

Comment: I think you do not need the parent definition there, starter-jpa and starter-web should be enough, would you remove the parent tag part then try to compile again?

Comment: Parent tag to manage the whole spring dependencies, If he remove it from pom, they will have to use specific version for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its dependency conflict or something wrong in m2 directory, So You can try to delete org/springframework from m2 directory, Then `mvn clean install`, Maybe it will work fine.